# How to access Google Drive APIs from my Web API

Tags: angular, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-webapi, access-token, google-oauth

I have a web API which is being used by a angular app and an android app. Scenario is user will log in to my angular app / Android app using google Oauth 2.0. I have a specific module where the user can upload files. I have to store the file in user's google drive. How can I do this? Please explain the workflow like where to get access token, how to pass it to my API, how to use that to access drive API.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to guide you to the [Browser Quickstart article](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) that shows you how to access the Drive API from a web-browser.

If you'd like your 3rd party API (your own) performing this access, you will need to share your application configuration between your Angular/Android applications and your custom API. This is to comply with the [Google Identity Platform guidelines for Cross-client tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#policy).

In short, this means that, while your front-end and back-end are separate (in your eyes) the users are expected to interact with your application as a single entity.

With your project setup on the [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com) (with a Project, Consent Screen, Scopes and Libraries activated) you are able to create different credentials for your application.

For the sake of security, you should define the minimal amount of access required for your application to run. This means that, if you only need to read files (as an example) you should not request permissions that allow you to delete files.

Once you have your Credentials created, you can use them on your front-end and back-end independently to access the data you want. Your user will be guided thru the [OAuth2.0 Authorization flow](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing).

On this step, you will be handed with a short-lived AccessToken (with an expiration date) and a [long-lived RefreshToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#save_refresh_tokens_in_long-term_storage) (rarely expires).

When you request information from the API, you must send your AccessToken to validate your identity. When your AccessToken expires, you should request a new one by providing your RefreshToken. You should code your application to request for a new AccessToken when it expires.

If you'd like to access data from the back-end based on the login information on the front-end, then you need to share this RefreshToken and/or AccessTokens when communicating with your back-end.

There are multiple ways to do this and the implementation, benefits and disadvantages greatly vary from your decisions.

Personally, I would perform all authentication on the Back-end and use the front-end simply as a proxy for your information.

I hope this explanation helps you on your way. Good luck!